# Drupal 7: Import CSV to multiple taxonomy fields in node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have started a new Drupal project where I have multiple vocabularies, and a node that includes these vocabularies as fields with auto complete boxes. I have a CSV file and I wonder if there is any way using feeds or eventually migrate module to make the columns create tags under different vocabularies. Note that the tags them self might require more than one value to be created as well.

To try to show what I mean this might be a row in the CSV-file:
Content_type_ID;Tax1_name;Tax1_email;Tax2_ID;Tax2_Year;Tax2_Month

Where Tax1 and Tax2 are different vocabularies as fields in my content type.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds).

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.

[Documentation  link](http://drupal.org/node/622696).

Answer (score 0):

also take a look at [Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate), but "Feeds module" very easy to use.